# Why I don't see DLLs and dotnet.wasm being loaded on a Blazor WebAssembly app in Browser > Dev Tools > Network?

Tags: .net, blazor, webassembly

I am fiddling with the default VS2019 (16.6.5) Blazor WebAssembly project. However when I look at *Chrome (or Firefox or Edge) > Developer Tools [F12] > network*, with *Disable Cache* enabled, I don't see much being loaded?

[image: Blazor wasm]

In the *Dev Tool > Sources* I can see that *dotnet.wasm* has been loaded somehow.

[image: dotnet.wasm in sources]

And by reading some articles like [this one](https://blazordev.it/blazor/intro/2020/02/11/blazor-webassembly.html) I see screenshots that show DLL and wasm being loaded.

[image: Devb Tool Network on Blazor wasm]

**Why don't I see that?**

---

Edit: Ok I succeed to see DLLs loaded like I want only **when starting debugging the Blazor WebAssembly project from VS2019**. When I start the project without debugging, I still get the same lightweight load as in the first screenshot. **Why?**

Comment: Have you tried to check the display on "Source" tab? Your last screenshot point to "Network" tab, the previous screenshot show display under "Source" tab.

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono screenshots 1) and 3) shows the same browser > Developer Tools > network view. The screenshot 2) is just here to double check I am running a Blazor wasm app and make sure it is not a Blazor Server app.

Comment: I see then in Chrome all the time. FireFox looks more like what you have. I have no idea what settings are involved.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Blazor WASM changed the loading behaviour just before RTM version 3.2 was released (May 2020) so the examples *prior* to this demonstrate the old behaviour.

When a Blazor WASM application loads, it creates a manifest and checksum for each DLL, this is loaded in `blazor.boot.json`

[image: WASM network trace]

The Blazor code will check for these files (and the checksum) in the Browser's Cache storage. Note this is not the same cache the browser uses for normal content, e.g. HTML, CSS etc.

If they're not present (the first run) they are loaded. You can see the files that were loaded here:

[image]

These files are loaded on the first run. In future page views, if the filename and checksum matches, it won't be reloaded *even if you select the browser's **"Empty Cache and Hard Reload"***

Why? This makes sense because files like `mscorlib.dll` won't have changed due to an app recompiling. This isn't JavaScript, it's a binary. The SHA256 checksum verifies it's the same file.

However your Blazor app DLLs will change if you edit and recompile. If they do they get reloaded:

[image: app change results in BlazorApp1.dll reloading]

If you want to force a full reload, you can navigate to the Browsers Cache (under *Application* in Chrome developer tools), and select Delete for your site.

Comment: I assume that running in incognito mode and closing it will also work for cleaning the cache? (Cache will be hold only as long as the process exists)

Comment: @Sebastian I just tried that on .net 6 blazor wasm and yes, it works as you expect